# Explicit Wait is not working on an AppiumWebElement while using ByAndroidUIAutomator locator

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am using C# Client to test an android app.
Appium version: 1.13

I came across a situation wherein I was using the below piece of code to explicitly wait for an element to get displayed and it didn't work.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => driver.FindElement(new ByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Test\")")).Displayed);
```

whereas, the Appium driver waited for 10 seconds when I had changed the locator from ByAndroidUIAutomator to By.Xpath

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@text='Test']")).Displayed);
```

To my surprise, ByAndroidUIAutomator waited for 5 seconds when I had used Implicit wait.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Now I am curious to know as to why it worked for the Implicit wait and not for the explicit wait.

**Error Message when I used explicit wait is as follows:**

Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your usage of the `ByAndroidUIAutomator` is correct. My expectation is that you should amend it to instantiate the appropriate [UISelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html) like:

```
new ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UISelector().text(\"Test\")");
```

References:

- [AndroidElementTest.cs](https://github.com/appium-boneyard/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/dotnet/AppiumDotNetSample/Android/AndroidElementTest.cs#L94)
- [Android Find By UIAutomator](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+Android+Find+By+UIAutomator)
- [Usage Of UiSelector – MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator](https://blog.imaginea.com/usage-of-uiselector-mobileby-androiduiautomator/)

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri for taking some time out to help me.

driver.FindElement(new ByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Test\")")) actually works even if i dont use "new UiSelector()." . You can give it a try.

Btw I tried the below code as per your suggestion and it had failed to wait for the element.

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => driver.FindElement(new ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Test\")")).Displayed);